# Как сделать хорошие скриншоты для Google Play?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play

Меня интересует как в некоторых приложениях, скриншоты наложены на макет устройства[image: пример]

Как так сделать?

Comment: Photoshop, не ?

Comment: @iFr0z , не лажу  с ними

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нашел наверное самое идеальное решение для быстрых и "ленивых" скринов.
Приложение на смартфон Screener. Сразу делает скриншот в макет, очень удобно.
[Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.toastcode.screener)

Answer (score 4):

В открытом доступе лежит огромное количество "макетов" телефонов, в которые можно вставить ваши скрины. Для этого не нужен огромный опыт работы с ФотоШопом - достаточно любого графического редактора (пэйнт, гимп и т.д.). 
Главное не лениться и найти тот макет телефона, которы Вам по душе.

Например [тут](http://beloweb.ru/dizayn-sayta/luchshaya-kollektsiya-besplatnyih-maketov-iphone-v-psd.html)
или [тут](http://ru.freepik.com/free-psd/smart-phone-mockups-psd_686780.htm)

ну а вообще [вот этим](https://www.google.ru/search?q=%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%82%20%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0&newwindow=1&espv=2&biw=1280&bih=616&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjeubWj38LNAhVyb5oKHTeuDzUQsAQIGw#) нужно учиться пользоваться :-)

UPD:
Вот эти бампера я использовал, возможно пригодится
[первый](http://s48.radikal.ru/i119/1606/69/e0e1405c0aa1.png) [второй](http://s019.radikal.ru/i644/1606/cc/b4935340a388.png) [беленький:)](http://s41.radikal.ru/i093/1606/86/7189f33b682c.png)

Comment: я искал, но в основном это макеты ios или приложений без устройства

Comment: тебе нужен макет какого то конкретного производителя?

Comment: нет, можно noname, но не похожим на ios, типа nexus

Comment: Добавил макеты, которые я использовал, возможно понравится какой-нибудь. Если что то не нравится - гугли)) на самом деле их очень много в открытом доступе ... ну либо можно самому дорисовать

Comment: спасибо. последние то что нужно

Answer (score 2):

Android Studio, эмулятор, кнопка ALT+PrtSc

Но вообще то это довольно спорный момент, по поводу "красивости" таких скриншотов. В гуглплее вам приложение надо показать, а не отъедать 20% полезного пространства никому не нужной картинкой телефона

Comment: Такой макет, насколько я знаю нужно самому рисовать на уже после всего контент поверх клеить)